# invalid expression: Invalid or unexpected token in Vue.js for-loop

Tags: vue.js

I have a v-for div like bellow:

```html
<div
              v-for="(item_disk, index_disk) in $store.state.buy_physicalserver_disk_list"
            >

            <Button 
              :type="get_choose_disk_type(item_disk)"
              :key="index_disk"
              @click="select_disk(item_disk)"
                 >
              {{ item_disk.content }}  // if I comment this line it will works fine.
                 </Button>
          </div>
```

I will get error in this case.

```
invalid expression: Invalid or unexpected token in "\n     "+_s(item_disk.content)+"\n        " Raw expression: {{ item_disk.content }}
```

See my code, if I comment the `{{ item_disk.content }}`, there will not have this issue.

Comment: Where does that `this.$store.state.buy_physicalserver_disk_list` come from? is that component data?

Comment: Is this in your template? You don't call the data with $this in the template, just the variable name.

Comment: Seems pretty clear; it doesn't like something in `item_disk.content`. What are the values of that?

Comment: the `item_disk.content` is just a string.

Answer (score 2):

I know this issue, use

```
<Button>{{item.content}}</Button>
```

get the error, but if I use

```
<Button v-text="item.content"></Button>
```

there will not have this issue.